# Matrix info extraction

Tags: objective-c, ios, matrix

I am back with my converter app problems.
As the internet clearly told me using if-else's for converting was bad, i tried to get data of a matrix instead. This is my attempt;

```
float convertFrom = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
float convertTo = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];
float input = [inputText.text floatValue];
float to = convertTo;
float from = convertFrom;
float convertValue = input;


int matrix [5] [5] = {
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {2,4,6,8,10},
    {3,6,9,12,15},
    {4,8,12,16,20},
    {5,10,15,20,25}};




NSString *MTPA = [[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:
                         @" %i %i ", matrix [[%f][%f], from, to]];
```

So what i want this code to do, is to take the value of the units currently in the UIPickerWheel, use it as coordinates for what number to take from the int, and later on put in in a float for calculation. This is just a test to see if it works. 
Is it impossible to use float's as co-ordinates for a matrix, or am i just doin' it wrong?

Comment: Arrays and matrices have *integer* indices, I do not understand why you use *float*. - The syntax of your last statement is completely wrong. An element of the matrix is accessed with `matrix[from][to]` (where `from` and `to` are integers in the range 0 .. 4 in your case).

Comment: Exactly what we wanted! Can you please explain how we could do that?

Comment: `_convertRates` already seems to be an array with the conversion factor for each unit. Why do you need the matrix at all?

Comment: Because I am half retarded when it comes to coding, and I can't manage to make the units into something useful. And, some people at another question I had said that was bad, and that I should use a matrix instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a matrix for unit conversions is a bad way to do this.

Pick a “fundamental unit”.  For example, if you're converting units of length, pick meters as your fundamental unit.

Create a `UnitDefinition` struct that holds the name of a unit and the conversion factor to convert that unit to the fundamental unit:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long long toFundamentalUnitNumerator;
    unsigned long long toFundamentalUnitDenominator;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *unitName;
} UnitDefinition;
```

Then create an array holding the units you want to support:

```
static UnitDefinition unitDefinitions[] = {
    { 1, 1000000, @"micron" },
    { 1, 1000, @"millimeter" },
    { 1, 100, @"centimeter" },
    { 1, 10, @"decimeter" },
    { 1, 1, @"meter" },
    { 10, 1, @"decameter" },
    { 100, 1, @"hectometer" },
    { 1000, 1, @"kilometer" },
    { 1000000, 1, @"megameter" },
    { 254, 10000, @"inch" },
    { 9144, 10000, @"yard" },
    { 160934, 100, @"mile" }
};
```

You'll also need a constant for the number of units in the array:

```
#define kUnitDefinitionCount (sizeof unitDefinitions / sizeof *unitDefinitions)
```

Now you can implement the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return kUnitDefinitionCount;
}
```

and you can implement the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol like this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return unitDefinitions[row].unitName;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self updateResultView];
}
```

and you can implement `updateResultView` like this:

```
- (void)updateResultView {
    UnitDefinition *fromUnit = &unitDefinitions[[unitsPicker_ selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    UnitDefinition *toUnit = &unitDefinitions[[unitsPicker_ selectedRowInComponent:1]];

    double input = inputField_.text.doubleValue;
    double result = input
        * fromUnit->toFundamentalUnitNumerator
        * toUnit->toFundamentalUnitDenominator
        / fromUnit->toFundamentalUnitDenominator
        / toUnit->toFundamentalUnitNumerator;
    resultLabel_.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6g", result];
}
```